# How to create the custom tabs in visualforce page using custom object?

Tags: visualforce, javascript, tab

I need to create four custom tabs, It contains individual information.How to create the custom tabs in visualforce page using custom object ? please help me and give me any related examples.

Comment: your question is very unclear. you want tabs inside your visualforce page or you want 4 tabs from different object near standard objects tabs like Account, Contact, Opportunity

Comment: @ Himanshu, I want inside visualforce page